# Meteor is saving images correctly but I can't retrieve them

Tags: meteor

With the following collection;

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("images", {   bucket: "my-bucket" });

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {   stores: [imageStore] });

Images.allow({   insert: function () {
      return true;
    },   update: function () {
      return true;
    },   remove: function () {
      return true;
    },   download: function () {
      return true;
    } });
```

I can successfully store and upload images to S3 - The image uploads fine and is saved in the Mongo DB fine.

But when I do;

```
Images.find().count()
```

It will return 0

```
Images.find().fetch()
```

Returns an empty array.

If I run `meteor mongo` and use the query `db.cfs.images.filerecord.find().count()` it will return 6 (the correct number)

Wondering what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to publish your `images` collection if you're removed auto publish.

**Server**:

```
Meteor.publish("images", function() {
    return Images.find(); //Narrow this down to the images that should be viewable
});
```

Then on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("images");
```